# Reapply commits while ignoring all space changes with Git

Tags: git, whitespace

I am trying to merge a branch that has a bunch of commits (~20). However the first commit is about re-indenting the whole code *properly* and all subsequent commits also contain whitespace changes, which I do not want.
I am trying to reapply all those commits but I don't know how to tell git to ignore space changes.

Yet I tried `git format-patch -20 --ignore-all-space` followed by `git apply *.patch` on a clean branch, but this obviously fails since patchs are individually formatted with space changes of their ancestors.

Basically I'd like to have the same history but without spaces changes:

```
      A - B - C - D
     /       
P - Q         
     \       
      A'- B'- C'- D' (spaces trimmed)
```

**edit**: To clarify which commits contain what.

1. A - reindenting a whole file named *foo* (replacing `tabs` with `spaces`). I'd like to **drop** it.
2. B - applying valid code changes in *foo*. I'd like to **keep** it.
3. C - applying valid code changes AND reindenting another file *bar*. I'd like to **keep only** code changes (keeping spaces changes for the modified lines)
4. D - applying valid code changes in *foo* and *bar*, given the facts that they now use `spaces` instead of `tabs`. I'd like to **keep** these changes too.

Comment: So, is `A` the commit that "is about re-indenting the whole code properly"? Could you please clarify on that in the question?

Comment: Also, could you please clarify whether the commits contain space *and* code changes in the same *line*, or only in the same *file*?

Comment: I edited the question; does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `D` position/branch. Then remove all spaces as you want. Then add & commit again.

```
$ git checkout <D-position-branch-name>
```

Change what you want (remove all spaces as you want)

```
$ git commit -am 'Remove spaces'        # add & commit your changes
$ git push origin HEAD                  # push your changes to remote
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this while having `Q` checked out:

```
git merge -s ours A
git merge -X ignore-space-change D
```

The first does not actually change any code in Q, but just "pretends" the merge to have happened by creating a "dummy" merge commit. This is useful to ignore `A` in the subsequent incremental merge.

The next merge command does merge the remaining commits from `D` down to `B`, but not `A` anymore.

To quote the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> *ours* resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches.
>
> *ignore-space-change* treats lines with the indicated type of whitespace change as unchanged for the sake of a three-way merge. Whitespace changes mixed with other changes to a line are not ignored. [...]
>
> - If *their* version only introduces whitespace changes to a line, *our* version is used;
> - If *our* version introduces whitespace changes but *their* version includes a substantial change, *their* version is used;
> - Otherwise, the merge proceeds in the usual way.

Comment: I actually want to *drop* re-indenting changes from A (and others). I tried `git checkout Q && git merge -Xignore-space-change A` but every space changes are merged too..

Comment: I see, our edited question now makes that clearer. Please give my updated answer a try.

Comment: That's strange. While it works for commit B and C, when merging commit D all the space changes from A are getting applied, as if D required them. But if I stop to commit C, `foo` file looks sane...